# What is the fastest algorithm for calculating nth term of Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: ds.algorithms

If we exclude methods that include precalculating of all Fibonacci numbers up to a sufficiently large number of n what would be the fastest  algorithm for calculating nth term of Fibonacci sequence?

I guess that Iterative and Matrix algorithms should be faster than Analytic and Recursive algorithms, (see [this paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Emhock/SSL/fibcalc.pdf)).

On [this page](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/161/960109.html) I have found five different algorithms. According to author the fastest is a Matrix algorithm that uses $O(\log n)$ arithmetic operations.

Comment: Not really a research level question. Computer Science SO is the right place but I think if you read the paper and page you have shared you will get the answer.

Comment: I think the question is probably fine here.

Comment: That matrix algorithm uses $O(\log n)$ arithmetic operations, not $O(\log n)$ "time", unless you can multiply two $n$-digit numbers in constant time.

Comment: In terms of bit complexity, recursive algorithms which go from $n$ to $2n$ in each step (such as here: http://gmplib.org/manual/Fibonacci-Numbers-Algorithm.html) take time $O(M(n))$, where $M(n)$ is the time needed for multiplication of two $n$-bit integers (the current best bound is $M(n)=n\,\log n\,2^{O(\log^*n)}$ by Fürer). I can't imagine you could do better (up to a multiplicative constant).

Comment: I suppose the matrix powering algorithm is a different formulation of the same thing.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks..I have found this one :    [3B fast recursion](http://cubbi.com/fibonacci.html) algorithm .

Comment: @pedja: Note that the complexity estimates they give for 3A and 3B have one $\log n$ factor too many (they apparently didn't realize that the times spent in each of the $\log n$ iterations make roughly a geometric series).

Answer (score 6):

According to [this Project Nayuki link](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms), Fast doubling is even faster than Fast Matrix, because redundant calculations are removed.